# How do I fully uninstall Quark Express on mac?

Tags: macos

The vendor says to drag the application to the trash, but the application was installed using an installer that required admin permissions at several points. What else needs to be removed?

Comment: Fully uninstall an Adobe product?  Buy a new Mac  :/

Comment: Quark isn't and has never been an Adobe product...

Answer (score 2):

I found the following files and directories by looking in likely places for files or directories with Quark in the name:

- /Library/Spotlight/QuarkExpress.mdimporter
- /Library/Application Support/Quark
- /Library/Frameworks/QuarkUpdateInterface.framework
- /Library/Preferences/Quark
- /Library/LaunchAgents/com.quark.quarkupdate.agent.plist
- /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.quark.QXPHelper.plist
- /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.quark.quarkupdate.quhelper.plist
- /Library/Preferences/com.quark.quarkupdate.plist
- /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.quark.QXPHelper
- /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.quark.quarkupdate.quhelper
- ~/Library/Application Support/Quark
- ~/Library/Caches/QuarkAutoUpdate.plist
- ~/Library/Caches/QuarkConfig
- ~/Library/Caches/QuarkUpdate Installer.pkg
- ~/Library/Caches/com.quark.QuarkXPress
- ~/Library/Logs/Quark
- ~/Library/Preferences/Quark
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.quark.QuarkXPress.XTensions.QuarkXPressCEFRenderer.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.quark.QuarkXPress.plist

I also found my test project in:

- ~/Documents/Quark
- ~/Documents/Quark_Backup